# Detecting goals blocked on a foosball table

Tags: sensors

I am trying to find a way to detect when a goal is blocked on a foosball/kicker table. I have a HD camera  above the table and a laser sensor built into each goal. The lasers can detect when a goal is made and the speed of the ball. The camera was my attempt at ball tracking however the ball speed is upward 30kmh at times. I cannot get the frame rate of the camera high enough to reliably track and detect if a goal was blocked. I can get the frames high enough but with shutter speed that high the ball is too dark to see.  I am looking for an alterative method. Any ideals would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is a high-intensity short-duration pulsed light source an option (synced to acquisition)? hi speed industrial vision systems all do that. Maybe IR band if you want to hide it from humans, not sure what that does to speed/cost tho.

Comment: Fluorescent ball and UV lighting?

Comment: we have considered UV lighting but its not a desired solution.  @PeteW Ir would be the way to go. I would have to replace my camera it has a built in IR filter. Could you recommend a product?

Comment: @Timothy, can't really, I did some computer vision 20-21 years ago with ancient precision strobe lights, labview NI vision DAQ, silhouette images to generate crisp edges from shiny objects (ball bearings), and some homebrew code but it was clunky and expensive. The names I've seen for the factory automation are Keyence (very nice products) and perhaps Cognex, Panasonic, but again you would be paying a lot extra for the compatibility with PLC automation. Maybe research cameras that can do high speed IR, and have an ext trigger, and get a separate IR strobe source also with a trigger??

Comment: you're going to need either a bigger lens,  more light, or a better sensor

Comment: Thanks for the advice. it will take me a few weeks to order and implement the lights. As soon as I am done I will check back and upvote an answer. In the mean time if anyone has a none camera based possibility. I am would appreciate hearing it.